How to modify /etc/hosts file for root domain in a vps server?
I am in the process of changing the reverse DNS of a VPS. The VPS is showing a subdomain (vmi000.contaboserver.net) as the hostname, I want to use my own root label domain as the hostname. Consider the sample script from /etc/hosts in a VPS server -
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vmi000.contaboserver.net vmi000

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff99::1 ip6-allnodes
ff99::2 ip6-allrouters
46.250.333.33    vmi000.contaboserver.net vmi000

I want to update the hostname as one of my domain names (like: example.com). Are there any wrong in the below script?
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       example.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff99::1 ip6-allnodes
ff99::2 ip6-allrouters
46.250.333.33    example.com

JFYI: I also updated the content of /etc/hostname with example.com.

Your domain changes are okay, but even if you intend to put a whole FQDN in /etc/hostname, you should still make sure that the short hostname (i.e. just the first component, example in your case) also resolves to some local address. So your /etc/hosts lines should say:
127.0.1.1 example.com example
 - or -
46.250.333.33 example.com example

(Though having both lines is redundant. Either the eth0 IP or the loopback IP is enough.)
In other words, both the output of hostname and the output of hostname -s should resolve to the system's own address – the following commands should all work:
ping -4 $(hostname)
ping -4 $(hostname -s)
ping -6 $(hostname)        # optional
ping -6 $(hostname -s)     # optional
getent hosts $(hostname)
...

Personally, I think a root domain is a pretty poor choice for a system hostname.
Also: the multicast addresses should start with ff00::, not ff99::. (Though those entries are entirely useless either way, but the fact that it says ff99::1 is a bit odd.)

why do you think a root domain is a poor choice for a system hostname?

If you name the server after your website, it kind of implies that you only have one server, ever, and that the server only hosts that one website, ever. It's like if the CEO of Apple had changed their name to "Mr. CEO Apple". (I'm a bit old-fashioned and from the era when it was more common to name servers after LoTR characters or whatever, but this holds as well as for generic names - maybe eventually you'll have web2, web3, mail1-2, etc.)

It also doesn't play will with the "domain suffix search" feature, where the system would expand queries for bare names to add the suffix automatically. Suppose you do have multiple servers some years later, and you're on "web01.example.com" and do "ssh mail03" it goes to "mail03.example.com", but if you're on just "example.com", that becomes... "mail03.com"? Not necessarily harmful but a bit messy.
